# Android update row int ormlite

Tags: java, android, sql-update, ormlite

I use `ormlite` in my Android project and I have problem with update data.
Here is my function which save and update data.

```
public void saveDeadline(){
    if (getIntent().getExtras() == null){
        try {
            Deadline newDeadline = new Deadline(deadlineStr, fromStr, toStr);
            deadlineDao.create(newDeadline);
       }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   } else {
        try {
           Deadline newDeadline = new Deadline(deadlineStr, fromStr, toStr);
           deadlineDao.update(newDeadline);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here my Entity class:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "deadline")
public class Deadline{

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    private String deadlineName;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    private String deadlineStart;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
    private String deadlineEnd;

    public Deadline() {
        super();
    }

    public Deadline(String deadlineName, String deadlineStart, String deadlineEnd) {
        this.deadlineName = deadlineName;
        this.deadlineStart = deadlineStart;
        this.deadlineEnd = deadlineEnd;
    }

    // removed getters and setters    
}
```

My application can't update existing data?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> My application can't update existing data? What am I doing wrong?

Whenever you ask for help with Java programs, you should always look for and post the exception including the caused messages.  In your case, if you look at your Android logs, I suspect you will see something like the following message:

```
Cannot update deadline because it doesn't have an id field
```

Do use things like `dao.update(...)` or `dao.delete(...)` you need to have a field that you mark as being the identity field either with `id = true` or `generatedId = true` in your `@DatabaseField` annotation.

Take a look a the example on the [ORMLite home page](http://ormlite.com/) and in the docs:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "accounts")
public class Account {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String name;
```

If this is *not* the problem then be sure to post the exception messages.